# Query embedded documents with mongo engine

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

so I'm using **mongoengine** to query embedded documents.

**schema: project**

```py
class _StatusFields(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
    start_time = mongoengine.DateTimeField()

class _Status(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
    start = mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField(
        _StatusFields, default=_StatusFields()
    )
    complete = mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField(
        _StatusFields, default=_StatusFields()
    )
class Project(mongoengine.Document):
    status = mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField(_Status,  default=_Status),
    location = mongoengine.StringField()
```

As you can see, I am using the **_Status** as an embedded document in the **Project**. I need to query the **status** in the project, that is an embedded document.

So this is the code that I have tried:

```py
filter = {'status__in': ['complete']}
project_objects = Project.objects(**filter).all()
```

But I get this error: 
`mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError: Querying the embedded document '_Status' failed, due to an invalid query value`

It works for strings and objectIds, but it does not seem to add for embedded documents.

Can someone please tell me what is the right way for querying an embedded documents?

Answer (score 0):

Project.status is an EmbeddedDocument (i.e: a nested structure), you are querying that field using a string but it expects an EmbeddedDocument instance. Depending on what you want to achieve (either querying Project.status or Project.status.complete), you can do:

```
# Saving an object in db
now = datetime.utcnow()
status = _Status(start=_StatusFields(start_time=now), complete=_StatusFields(start_time=now))
Project(status=status, location='whatever').save()

# Fails because Project.status is not a string so can't be queried using a string
# Project.objects(status__in=['complete'])

# queries Project.status.start_time
Project.objects(status__start__start_time=now)   

# queries Project.status using a _Status object
status_object = _Status(start=_StatusFields(start_time=now), complete=_StatusFields(start_time=now))
Project.objects(status__in=[status_object])
```